# Wix setup does not run installation

Tags: c#, installation, wix

> Hello, I have Wix Setup 3.1 Build an installer. On only one pc i have an issue that the Installation of my exe does not run. The progressbar is invisible and nothing complete. The Installation area is a nass Partition. Older Software Versions with wix run on this pc. Other computers with the newest Software Version does not have this problem with the exe Installation

Comment: You are installing to a network folder? Is this the only computer where you try to do this? Installers are primarily designed to target local folders. What are the features of your installer? File copy only? Custom actions?

Comment: What does a log file say?